# C Language - K&R 1st vs 2nd Edition?

Tags: books, c

I'm planning to buy a book to learn C Language. Many say K&R is a must-have book for C programmers so I chose it. I see that there are two editions. What are the differences between them?

Comment: Usually if a book has a 2nd edition, buying it is a no-brainer. It's the updated version of the first edition.

Comment: Thanks for asking this! I have my father's first edition copy of K&R from 1978, but have been somewhat uncertain about whether or not I should just buy the second edition, with the latest printing (42nd).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There may be a few cases where a first edition is preferred for some reason or other, but this is definitely *not* one of them.

If you want to learn C, the second edition is *clearly* preferred in this case. The first edition teaches a version of C that's been obsolete for *decades*. C has maintained enough backward compatibility that most of the code in the first edition *will* probably still work with a current compiler, but it's *definitely* not written the way you want to write C code any more.

Comment: The 2nd edition is also written in a way that you wouldn't want to write C code any more. Because the original was written long before good/bad programming practice and style was even invented.

Comment: @Lundin: Their ideas of good/bad programming practice and style may have differed from yours, but the idea had certainly been invented (and IMO, where you disagree with them on these matters, chances are much better that you're wrong than they are).

Comment: No this isn't just my own opinion, but the opinion shared by most leading C programming experts. Pick up any code snippet from K&R and run it through a modern static analysis tool - see for yourself. They were experts in the 70s, more than 30 years ago. The computer industry, as well as computers themselves, have undergone huge changes since then. Most of the syntax in K&R, and in C itself, is obfuscated by purpose so that they wouldn't waste so much HD space to store the source code. Programmers back then thought few source code characters equals good programs, it was all they knew.

Comment: @Lundin: Sorry, but I've yet to see a static analysis tool that seemed to be written by anybody as good as K and/or R either. If you want to get somewhere with this, you need to start by citing real data, not attempting to appeal to authority -- especially when you can't even cite an actual authority to whom you're appealing.

Comment: Name something K&R did that wasn't pure algorithms, that still holds as good C programming practice today? Without writing code full of flaws. As for authority, MISRA-C would be the most obvious, as it is the most modern, relevant update to C, in the form of a safe subset. If you want, I can run some K&R 2nd edition code through some static analysers tomorrow and come back with a list of questionable and/or plain dangerous programming practice from some snippets in that book.

Comment: 1. MISRA is intended for a specific application, not general use. 2. MISRA doesn't hold up very well under close scrutiny anyway (e.g., see Les Hatton's critques). 3. Static analysis is subject to the judgement of the analyzer's author -- it's still just attempting to defer to authority by proxy, depriving the (supposed) authority of even being able to exercise judgement about what's really acceptable.

Comment: 1. MISRA was originally intended for specific applications, but since it's goal is to make programs stable and bug-free, nothing is stopping you for using it as a general-purpose coding standard. 2. Hatton's critique about MISRA giving too many "false negatives" is valid, and there are a few odd rules. But at large, MISRA leads to better C programs (and most of it's contents are heavily influenced by Hatton's research). 3. Yes but you can set most static analyzers to validate according to relevant authority: MISRA, DO-178B, CERT etc etc.

Comment: As promised, a sample of how bad K&R 2ed is, taken from the first 23 pages: Bad practice: main must return int, since one can like assume that printf implies a hosted implementation. Bad practice: use of native primitive data types (int etc) instead of typedef:ed ones with a known size and signedness. Inefficient code/beginner mistake: using double literals when calculating float numbers. Bad/dangerous practice: getchar and scanf insteaf of fgets().

Comment: Bad practice: assignment inside conditions. Bad/dangerous practice: no braces after a control statement. Inefficient code: using double as loop iterator. Bug/typo p.22, assignment in condition (why it is bad practice in the first place). Bad practice: multiple assignments in one statement. I can continue this forever... The book is simply outdated and poor.

Comment: @Lundin: You not only can, but apparently will "continue like this forever...", exemplifying the fact that some people never learn. The only problems here are of your own making. I'd reply that it's your static checker that's "outdated and poor", but in reality "outdated" doesn't apply -- the nonsense it's spewing was *never* even close to correct.

Comment: These problems were found through manual review, not static analysis. Still, if you truly think that these classic, fundamental problems are something of my own making, you clearly know little to noting of the C language. These problems are widely recognized flaws. You can look them up at Stack Overflow and see that the vast majority of all C programmers agree. Or at the C.lang.FAQ. Or in MISRA. Or in Hatton's Safer C. Or in pretty much every other decent C book. Which fundamental C programming flaw in K&R that I pointed out is _not_ widely recognized as bad practice?

Comment: @Lundin: It may be open to argument that an assignment by itself as a condition (`if (a=b)`) *could* barely qualify as a poor practice. Something like on page 22 (`while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)`) bad practice shows not only ignorance of C, but of programming in general. Writing a loop like that with the assignment outside the condition leads to code that's either wrong, or more complex and error prone. Sorry, but on this one there's not even room for compromise: you're just dead wrong.

Comment: If you honestly want to complain about the code on page 22, there *is* one point that's far from optimal: checking for specific white-space characters instead of using `isspace`. That's quite clearly purely a matter of exposition though -- `isspace` simply isn't introduced until later in the book. Just about every book has that problem though: there's a lot you need to know before you can do even simple things really well. Rearranging the book to introduce `isspace` earlier would accomplish little or nothing.

Comment: Pretty much every compiler made the past 20 years warn against assignment inside conditions, and it is banned by MISRA. But of course you know better than every well-known compiler manufacturer! The typo/bug on p22 shows why, even K&R made the classic assignment bug right there, which they didn't even spot themselves before the book was released. Anyway, this discussion is going nowhere, since you won't recognize any programming authorities or believes by the vast majority of C programmers, if their statements were made after 1990...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1680/discussion-between-jerry-coffin-and-lundin)

Comment: I loved the first edition of K&R, but it went into recycling a long while ago when I realized it was of no practical use in the world with the second edition (and ANSI C) being the standard.  At this point, I don't recall if I even have my second edition book anymore...  The compilers I used had so many proprietary extensions that the reference for the exact compiler was all I ever used in practice...

Comment: @JerryCoffin, while I haven't read all of K&R, user29079 is entirely right to say that at least some of it is outdated. You only need to get half a dozen code samples into the book to find them [advocating data type choices that were obsoleted 16 years ago by C90](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503160/is-there-any-rational-reason-to-use-a-double-to-store-an-integer-when-precision) and no longer make any sense; I'm sure there's more similar issues be found. Even the second edition is an ancient book.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Please at least attempt to get your facts straight before posting. You're apparently referring to the addition of `long long`, but that didn't exist until C99. Also note that the question in this case was only which to choose between the first and second editions of the book. I'd tend to agree that if a third edition existed, it would probably be preferred to the second--but as-is, if you're going to read K&R at all, your only choices are the first edition or the second--and between them, the second is clearly preferable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oops, sorry, you're right about `long long` being C99. Still, what's at stake in your conversation with user29079 was explicitly *not* the choice between 1st and 2nd edition K&R - it was whether even K&R 2nd edition is outdated and shows practices that no longer make sense or seem bad in light of modern ideas about programming style. My factual error about when `long long` was introduced doesn't change the point that it clearly does show at least some such obsolete practices.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Even today, calling it obsolete is a bit premature--there are still a fair number of processors with floating point hardware, but not 64-bit integers in hardware. On such hardware, a `double` will still usually be substantially faster than a `long long`.

Comment: I'll get flamed for writing this, but... what a war..

Answer (score 6):

The second edition is written to ANSI C, which the first predated. That alone should make the second book the one to buy.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely the 2nd version. The first version doesn't cover ANSI C.

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves me right, K&R 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition was published in **1988**, to comply with the imminent release of ANSI-C (aka C89)

A lot has happened in the C world since then...

1. 1990 - adoption of C by ISO as ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (aka C90)
2. 1999 - new revised standard as ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (aka C99)
3. 2011 - further major revision as ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (aka C11)

Not to mention the work of MISRA and CERT-C (etc) to produce safer subsets.

I have a copy of both editions, but seldom refer to either...

Comment: Note that the 1989 ANSI and 1990 ISO C standards describe exactly the same language; the only difference between the documents is some added introductory material and a renumbering of the sections.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sir, I am Planning To Study Second Edition of the book, can you tell me the main differences it and C99 and C11 has , or point me to that question, I cannot seem to find it, I just want the differences, Does Second Edition is very outdated or still makes sense?

Comment: @SurajJain - the main differences are additions in C11 to support threads, atomics, alignment and generics - plus enhancements to complex and IEC floating point.

Comment: @Andrew I am planning to learn C From Second Edition of k & r, i want to which changes are there in it and c99 ? , Does K&R 2nd edition means c89 or there is a difference

Comment: Without wanting to restart the discussions further above, I would not start with K&R (of either edition) - there are more up-to-date works that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Andrew I wanted a trustfull source that is not very lenghty

Comment: @SurajJain: K&R2 covers the 1989/1990 version of C. Each edition of the standard includes a summary of the differences from the previous edition. See [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for C99, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for C11.

Comment: @KeithThompson Should I Read k&r 2nd Edition ? Or it would be not worthfull ?\